# What does the + method in Ruby do, exactly?

Tags: ruby, math, operators, addition

Imagine I want to write my own math operators like "+"

The simple version would be:

```
def plus(a,b)
    return a+b
end
```

But this is not what the real "+" does.

I want `3.add(4) # =>7`
But how do I tell ruby to take the object that I used my method on?

I tried

```
def add(c)
    return self+c
end
```

But I get the error message:

:in `<main>': private method`add' called for 3:Fixnum (NoMethodError)

Comment: Not a Ruby person, but I suspect your answer is a special variable either called `this` or `self`. That's how it's done in most object oriented languages.

Comment: Yeah but I use "self"  in my 2nd code example and it does not work.

Comment: Hm. Your error message specifically mentions that the method is private. Is there something you need to do to make that method public?

Comment: Well that could be. Unfortunately I have no idea how to do this/what this means since I am new and haven't read about public and private yet.

Comment: I don't think the error message you posted is correct. The message says `add`, but the method you defined is called `plus`. So I suspect you have not copied/pasted your exact code and error message.

Comment: I am not a ruby person, but it looks like someone who is has arrived.

Comment: oh right, but the error remains the same, updated it in my code

Comment: Yeah it seems. Thanks for the quick replies! :)

Comment: In which class did you define your `add` method? Please add the complete code of your class to your question, because your method looks fine and works without a hitch in my test cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem**

You defined the method:

```
def add(c)
  return self + c
end
```

and attempted to use it thus:

```
3.add(4) #=> NoMethodError: private method `add' called for 3:Fixnum
```

**Understanding this error message**

This error message tells you exactly what the problem is. I think your problem is simply that you don't understand how Ruby invokes methods on objects.

When Ruby sees `3.add(4)` it first looks at the *receiver*, `3`, and determines:

```
3.class #=> Fixnum
```

This tells it where the method `add` is defined: in the class `Fixnum` or in one of `Fixnum`'s ancestor's classes or modules.

So it looks for it there, doesn't find it, and issues an error message. We can confirm it's not there:

```
Fixnum.instance_methods.include?(:add)
  #=> false
```

**So where is `add` defined?**

You did define it, though, so where is it? Let's find out:

```
method(:add).owner
  #=> Object 

Object.instance_methods.include?(:add)
  #=> false
```

`Object.instance_methods` returns an array of all of *public* instance methods defined on `Object` and `Object`'s ancestors. `add` is not among those, so we conclude `add` is a *protected* or *private* method:

```
Object.protected_instance_methods.include?(:add)
  #=> false

Object.private_instance_methods.include?(:add)
  #=> true
```

Let's try invoking that method on an instance of `Object`:

```
Object.new.add(4)
  #=> NoMethodError: 
  #   private method `add' called for #<Object:0x007fdb6a27fa68>
```

That makes sense, considering that `Object#add` is private. We can, however invoke private methods with [Object#send](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Object.html#method-i-send):

```
Object.new.send(:add,4)
  #NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for #<Object:0x007fdb6a28e068>
```

As an exercise, make sure you understand the steps Ruby took that led to her raising this exception (that the instance method `+` is not defined on `Object`, or equivalently, that the instance of `Object` does not have a method `+`).

By the way, where did you define `add`? By that, I mean what what was the value of `self` when you defined it? Let's see:

```
self       #=> main
self.class #=> Object
```

We see that `add` must be defined on the class for which its receiver is an instance. (A mouthful, yes, but it's important, so make sure you understand that).

**Why is `Object#add` private rather than public?**

Consider:

```
def greet
  puts 'hi'
end

class A
end

A.private_instance_methods.include?(:add)
  #=> true 
A.new.send(:greet)
  #=> 'hi'
```

The is because `A` inherits `greet` from `Object`:

```
A.ancestors.include?(Object) #=> true
```

If `Object#greet` were public, every built-in class and every class you define would have a public instance method `greet`. That would result in a great deal of misery. (Suppose you had a method `great` and mistyped it `greet`!) Even the private `greet` could cause trouble.)

**Where should `add` be defined?**

Since `add.class => Fixnum`, we define it thus:

```
class Fixnum
  def add(other)
    self + other
  end
end

Fixnum.instance_methods.include?(:add) #=> true
3.add(4)                               #=> 7
```

Had I included the line `puts "self#{self}"` after `class Fixnum` it would have printed "Fixnum". Salting your code with `puts` statements that show the value of `self` often helps in understanding what's going on.

One last thing:

```
method(:add).owner
  #=> NameError: undefined method `add' for class `Object'
```

Why did this not return `Fixnum`? Since `method` has no explicit receiver (i.e., no `xx.method`), Ruby assumes the receiver to be `self`, which here is:

```
self #=> main
```

so she looks for the method `method` in `self.class => Object`, and you know what she finds (or, I should say, doesn't find).  Instead, we need to write:

```
Fixnum.instance_method(:add).owner #=> Fixnum
```

or

```
3.method(:add).owner #=> Fixnum
```

Here `3` can of course be replaced by any instance of `Fixnum`.

Note I've simplified this explanation somewhat. In searching for a method, Ruby also looks in the receiver's singleton class. This is not an issue for immediate objects (numbers, symbols, `true`, `false` and `nil`), however, as they do not have singleton classes:

```
3.singleton_class     #=> TypeError: can't define singleton
```

By contrast, for example:

```
[1,2].singleton_class #=> #<Class:#<Array:0x007fbcf18c01a8>>
```

Answer (score 1):

The plus-sign (+) in ruby can be overridden pretty much like any other method (you can look for operator-overloading):

```
class MyOperator
  attr_accessor :text
  def initialize(text)
    @text = text
  end
  def +(operand)
     "#{self.text} #{operand.text}"
  end

  def to_s
    self.text
  end
end


a = MyOperator.new "Hello"
b = MyOperator.new "World"


puts (a+b)
```

So there is not much magic to it. But you have to be careful if the overloading the operators make sense in your context.